# How to extract particular set of value from a file in Python?

Tags: python

I am stuck with the logic here... i have to extract some values from a text file that looks like this

```
AAA
+-------------+------------------+
|          ID |            count |
+-------------+------------------+
|           3 |             1445 |
|           4 |              105 |
|           9 |              160 |
|          10 |               30 |
+-------------+------------------+
BBB
+-------------+------------------+
|          ID |            count |
+-------------+------------------+
|           3 |             1445 |
|           4 |              105 |
|           9 |              160 |
|          10 |               30 |
+-------------+------------------+
CCC
+-------------+------------------+
|          ID |            count |
+-------------+------------------+
|           3 |             1445 |
|           4 |              105 |
|           9 |              160 |
|          10 |               30 |
+-------------+------------------+
```

I am not able to extract value from BBB alone and append it to a list like

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
text = f.readlines()
B_Values = []
for i in text:
    if i.startswith("BBB"):(Example)
       B_Values.append("only values of BBB")
    if i.startswith("CCC"):
       break

print B_Values
```

should result

```
['|           3 |             1445 |','|           4 |              105 |','|           9 |              160 |','|          10 |               30 |']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0].isalpha(): # is first character in the line a letter?
            curr = d.setdefault(line.strip(), [])
        elif filter(str.isdigit, line): # is there any digit in the line?
            curr.append(line.strip())
```

for this file, `d` is now:

```
{'AAA': ['|           3 |             1445 |',
         '|           4 |              105 |',
         '|           9 |              160 |',
         '|          10 |               30 |'],
 'BBB': ['|           3 |             1445 |',
         '|           4 |              105 |',
         '|           9 |              160 |',
         '|          10 |               30 |'],
 'CCC': ['|           3 |             1445 |',
         '|           4 |              105 |',
         '|           9 |              160 |',
         '|          10 |               30 |']}
```

Your `B_values` are `d['BBB']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state flag *bstarted* to track when the B-group has begun.
After scanning the B-Group, delete the three header rows and the one footer row.

```
B_Values = []
bstarted = False
for i in text:
    if i.startswith("BBB"):
        bstarted = True
    elif i.startswith("CCC"):
        bstarted = False
        break
    elif bstarted:
        B_Values.append(i)

del B_Values[:3]   # get rid of the header
del B_Values[-1]   # get rid of the footer
print B_Values
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid iterating over the already read lines. Call readline whenever you want to read the next line and check to see what it is:

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
B_Values = []
while i != "":
    i = f.readline()
    if i.startswith("BBB"): #(Example)
        for temp in range(3):
            f.skipline() #Skip the 3 lines of table headers
        i = f.readline()
        while i != "+-------------+------------------+" and i !="":
            #While we've not reached the table footer
            B_Values.append(i)
            i = f.readline()
        break

#Although not necessary, you'd better put a close function there, too.
f.close()

print B_Values
```

**EDIT**: @eumiro 's method is more flexible than mine. Since it reads all the values from all sections. While you can implement `isalpha` testing in my example to read all the values, still his method is easier to read.